# Too many points captured by onLocationChanged in android google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I'm working on an android app for tracking user's current location(using GPS) and make route on google maps when the location changes.

For saving route, I'm fetching the latitudes and longitudes of each location and storing it in a List, on clicking a button "Save", the list is converted to JSON and sent to the server for saving. It is working fine as the way it should.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    showLocation.setText("" + location.getLatitude() + " , " + location.getLongitude());
    drawLine(location, latLng);
    latLongsForRoute.add(latLng);
    for (LatLng latLong : latLongsForRoute) {
        Log.i("Latitude is: ", "" + latLong.latitude);
        Log.i("Longitude is: ", "" + latLong.longitude);
    }
}
```

But, the problem is even if a user moves for 1 km then it is giving me thousands of latitudes and longitudes which is too much data to save. And rest the case for a route of 10-15km length.

```
[
   {
      "latitude": 30.7084098,
      "longitude": 76.7030218,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7084009,
      "longitude": 76.7030315,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7083951,
      "longitude": 76.7030796,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7084004,
      "longitude": 76.7029865,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7083882,
      "longitude": 76.703018,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.708417,
      "longitude": 76.7030046,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7083921,
      "longitude": 76.7030199,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7084087,
      "longitude": 76.7029926,
      "zzCY": 1
   },
   {
      "latitude": 30.7083846,
      "longitude": 76.7029833,
      "zzCY": 1
   }
]
```

(These many points were obtained for 15-20 metre length)

How can I get less amount of data i.e. lesser number of latitude longitudes but with high accuracy and also the correct route.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using The Google Play services location APIs then while creating a LocationRequest Object you can adjust the following parameters.

```
    //the rate at which app prefers to receive location updates
    LocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    // the fastest rate with which the app can handle location updates
    LocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    //the smallest displacement in meters the user must move between location updates.
    LocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement();
```